# How to derive the `one` multiplicity constraint using the Alloy Kernel language?

Tags: alloy

I was reading Appendix C: Kernel Semantics of the Software Abstraction book (by Daniel Jackson, second edition, very nice read btw!) and found myself a bit stuck in understanding how to derive the `one` multiplicity constraint using the other kernel constructs.

I understand that `no` can be derived using `expr = none`, and `some` can be derived using the negation of the previous rule but I don't understand how to express the `one` (and thus `lone`) constraint using only the kernel constructs (or derivations).

I am probably missing something obvious but I don't see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'd express `one expr`

```
//there is some expr
not (expr = none)
//and all expr should be one and the same because there's only one expr. 
all x1,x2: expr | x1=x2
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! That is indeed a nice way to express it. I wonder whether there are more ways to do it.

Comment: mmmh, could be, I'd also be interested to see other solutions ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can define `one` like this:

```
one e iff
not all x: e | not x = x // e is non-empty
and
all x: e | all x': e | x = x' // e has no more than one member
```

Note that the kernel language is not sufficient to express higher order quantifications (which are supported by Alloy* but not very effectively by Alloy itself). So the quantifier gives us the notion of a singleton.

Daniel

Comment: Dear Daniel, sorry missed your answer before!
As I compare both answers your differs on the definition of `no expr` by rewriting this to the quantified version `not all x:e | not x = x` but the other constraint is similar to the one offered by Loïc. Thanks for your insight!